# Initial Conditions For Characteristic Projections

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Given $u_t=(u_x)^2$ and an initial condition $u(x,0)=\begin{cases}
 1-x & \text{ if } x \in [0,1) \\ 
 0 & \text{ if } x \in [1,\infty)
\end{cases} $

Using Charpit's equations by defining $F(x,y,u,p=u_x,q=u_t)= u_t-(u_x)^2 = 0$, and parameterising characteristic projections by $(s,\tau)$, we obtain

$q=p^2 \implies F=q-p^2$ and so characteristic projections are defined by $ t'(s)=1,x'(s)=-2p$ and on the projections, $p$ and $q$ vary according to;$ \dot{p}=\dot{q}=0$
and the solution is given by $u'(s)=q-2p^2=p^2-2p^2=-p^2$

Now the problem is defining conditions on s=0, I have the solutions(given below), but I have no intuitive idea of how they are yielded, from the initial conditions given.

The aformentioned conditions are given by (on $s=0$) : $t=0,x=\tau,u=1-\tau,p=\mu, q=\mu^2$

Answer (score 1):

An obvious solution for the PDE $\quad u_t=u_x^2\quad$ is :
$$u(x,t)=\alpha x +\alpha^2 t+\beta$$
With the conditions the solution is :
$$u(x,t)=\begin{cases}
 -x+t+1 & \text{ if } x \in [0,1) \qquad\qquad \alpha=-1\quad;\quad \beta=1 \\ 
 0 & \text{ if } x \in [1,\infty) \qquad\qquad \alpha=0\quad;\quad \beta=0
\end{cases} $$
Or with the Heaviside step function
$$u(x,y)=(-x+t+1)\text{H}(1-x)$$